# Chrome storage deleted after closing tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

when I close the tab and then open a new one ,all the storage is removed.I am using

```
var postsId = []
    chrome.storage.local.set({
                'posts': postsId
              });
```

and later I do :

```
chrome.storage.local.get({
                    posts: []
                  }, function(result) {
}
```

is there any other option to save the data without losing it ?

Thank you

Comment: The question isn't answerable in its current state. Edit it and add the relevant code. Most probably, you're using the asynchronous chrome.storage API [incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Answer (score 0):

If you access it immediately after you saved it, it works? Maybe you're trying to store a large item and it returns an error?

Comment: it works,I am able to get it,on page refresh it also saves, but when I close the tab it is gone.

Answer (score 0):

This was a stupid mistake .....

```
var postsId = []
```

was resetting the array each time...